# Why would a hospital not allow the recording of a baby's ultrasound video while in the lab?

Tags: pregnancy

I took my wife to take our first ultrasound. I was told be an operator/receptionist while we made an appointment that it is OK to bring a camcorder with us. But when we were there, the ultrasound technician told us another story. She said that camcorder is not allow to record our baby but they can provide us a 3 min copy of ultrasound movie from the lab's monitor instead. (Actually I wanted to see my wife face when she saw our baby for the first time, but DVD still better than nothing)

Is this a common practice in US or in PA? Is it the law? All my friends have their first ultrasound video to keep a good memory. (My friends are not in the US.) I still do not understand why they are not allow us to shoot our VDO.

Comment: Youtube returns 113,000 results for "First baby ultrasound" (https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=first+baby+ultrasound) So I guess some places allow to film :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to a friend of mine who is a nurse in obstetrics, the terms of the ultrasound machine purchase/lease typically only allow the hospital to use the ultrasound images for medical purposes.  Giving it to you to show off to your friends/family is not medical.

Some ultrasound manufacturers now let you log in to their web site and get those images for a fee, others allow the hospital to print you small copies and the hospital may or may not charge to recover the royalties paid to the ultrasound company for doing this.

Comment: (singing) _Money makes the world go round, the world go round, the world go round..._

Comment: that makes no sense to me. I don't know anyone who didn't get pictures and/or videos of the ultrasound images itself.

Answer (score 7):

My guess would be that it is due to liabilty fears. I doubt you could record anything in the place, in case you recorded them making a mistake and could then use the video as evidence in court.

Answer (score 4):

I'd concur with Turpie, there are lots of litigation issues surrounding medical procedures, some technicians may also just not like being recorded.  Many hospitals may have blanket policies to limit recordings to avoid litigation as well, far as I know there is no law but company and business policies tend to trump many things.  Might not hurt to check with the hospital to see what they say, especially since you want to document your baby and it's important to you - they might make an exception or give you more reason as to why.

Comment: I agree, and I really can understand an ultrasound tech not wanting to be filmed at work. That seems very invasive.